# File.Exists() returns false in Deleted event of FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher

I struggled into a problem. I have a synchronization program and I need to know if a watching item is a file or folder. Problem is when I'm checking file or folder exists - no matter what, if I'm checking a file, `File.Exists` always returns false:

```
private void onDelete(object o, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    if (Directory.Exists(e.FullPath))
        Directory.Delete(watched + e.Name, true);

    if (File.Exists(e.FullPath))
        File.Delete(e.FullPath);
}
```

Anyone see where the problem could be?

Comment: What is `e.FullPath` when you delete a file?

Comment: what do you get in `e.FullPath` ? and have you checked whether file in actual exists or not ?

Comment: Try to ouput `e.FullPath` using Console.WriteLine or MessageBox to see if you are manipulating a real path

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to find of file/folder on `onDelete`, this method would be triggered when file / folder is already deleted. So you must not get that file on folder as it is deleted and does not exists.

Comment: oh ... well, thanks. That didnt cross my mind. I will try fix it if i figure out how

Answer (score 0):

The FileSystemWatcher is a notification system, not a hook.

You don't intervene with the events it fires, so you don't have to delete the file yourself when a Deleted event gets raised: you receive such an event *after* the delete already occurred.

Answer (score 0):

As Adil has said in his answer, you're already too late. However, perhaps you could distinguish the items by the file name itself? If you're the only one creating the files and folders, you could estabilish a convention. For example, you could use a file extension, which you can then easily get from the file name (`Path.GetExtension`).

Other than that, you'd probably be stuck with having to keep account of all the files and folders in the directory, to make sure they're the type you want.